# Creating a forEach statement for a JavaScript tree of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, string, web

first of all, I’d like to say I’m **new** to Stack Overflow, so. If my question has errors in it please note I’m a newbie. **Anyways**, so I’m creating a pure JavaScript database and I’m using a string array that is in the same format as this:

```
var SampleArray = [{
  "Food" : [ "banana", "Strawberry", "grapes" ],
  "Vegitables" : [ "Carrot", "Peppers" ],
  "Words" : [ "hello", "Goodbye", "Grapes" ],
  "Adjectives" : [ "Good", "First" ]
}]
```

Hopefully you get the gist of the array part, but the real question is, how can i create a search box that uses something like forEach statement to find a certain variable within the array, like `"good”`.

**Note/edit**
I have moved the question to here [How to create a search system for a tree of javascript arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52855896/how-to-create-a-search-system-for-a-tree-of-javascript-arrays)

Comment: You database is malformed - you cannot mix array items and key/value pairs in this way: `"Food” : "banana”,
   "Strawberry”,`

Comment: I looked at a website called w3schools and they showed an array like that. But is there an equivalent way of achieving my goal even if i have to change the array layout?

Comment: I've just updated your question to valid javascript syntax. Is this the format you had in mind?

Comment: Yeah, but isn’t there a limit to how many things you can put in the array, inside of the array?

Comment: Not really - technically, the only limit would be process/computer memory. If "good" is the query, what do you want the search to return?

Comment: Yeah, now that you showed me that, i guess that works. Thanks! Oh and i want the console to log the object name, because later on I’m going to do more things with this

Comment: @DacreDenny why an array with a single object; why not just an object?

Comment: @slider that appeared to be the format of the data in the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the updated database format in your question, you could achieve basic search based on something like this:

```js
var SampleArray = [{
  "Food" : [ "banana", "Strawberry", "grapes" ],
  "Vegitables" : [ "Carrot", "Peppers" ],
  "Words" : [ "hello", "Goodbye", "Grapes" ],
  "Adjectives" : [ "Good", "First" ]
}]

function searchDatabase(query) {

  // For each object in array
  for(var object of SampleArray) {

    // Get list values of object
    var lists = Object.values(object)

    // For each list of object
    for(var list of lists) {

      // For each item of list
      for(var item of list) {

        // Look for item matching query. Locally convert to lower case to
        // avoid case sensitivity issues
        if(item.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
          return object
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log('search for good', searchDatabase('good') ? 'found' : 'not found')
console.log('search for bad', searchDatabase('bad') ? 'found' : 'not found')
```

Comment: Yeah, i see, i just wasn’t thinking i guess when i was creating my database, it coming out pretty well thanks to you guys, so thanks!

Comment: @RidleyNelson you're welcome - glad I could help :-)

Comment: Oh, Before anyone abandons this question, what if there is an array like “sample” : [“toy” : “car”, “hello” : “goodbye”] and i want to find the variable that goes with “toy”

Comment: @RidleyNelson that should work as well however you'd need to replace the `:` (ie between toy and car, and,  hello and goodbye) with `,` characters then simply add that to the database and search for say "car" using the function provided in the answer

Comment: so you’re saying i cant do something like “song” : [“artist” : “”, “mp3source” : “”]

Comment: Correct - that would be invalid javascript syntax. You would need to do something like this: `“song” : [{ “artist” : “”, “mp3source” : “” }]`

Comment: That’s what i am doing currently, but I don’t know how to implement the statement you answered with into my code, like I don’t know how to use it with the “song” : [{ “artist” : “”, “mp3source” : “” }]

Comment: Perhaps open a new question showing the code you currently have and I can help you there

Comment: I will open tomorrow because i can only ask a question every 90 minutes. ill post the link below here **OR** you can go to my github repository and comment on it.

Comment: @RidleyNelson yip not a problem

Comment: Here is the link to my gist https://gist.github.com/Ridley-nelson17/1b3df3c99a6ae43428792ab0dce22aad#file-database-js