# How to create a search system for a tree of javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Yesterday, i asked a question about searching for arrays, here’s my array:

```
"Songs": [{
    "title": "", "Source": "", "SongArt": "", "artist": "", "explicit": false
 }]
```

Essentially I’m creating a cluster of songs, i want to create something that i can search the title of the song up, then i can get the source url from it.

```
"Songtitle": [{
    "title": "", "Source": "mp3", "SongArt": "", "artist": "", "explicit": false
 }],
"Songtitle": [{
    "title": "", "Source": "mp3", "SongArt": "", "artist": "", "explicit": false
 }],
"Songtitle": [{
    "title": "", "Source": "mp3", "SongArt": "", "artist": "", "explicit": false
 }],
"Songtitle": [{
    "title": "", "Source": "mp3", "SongArt": "", "artist": "", "explicit": false
 }],
```

As i mentioned previously, My goal here is to use something like a `<input>` and search for the variable that goes with “Source”. I got an answer yesterday, and i am trying to use something like it to achieve my goal. Below is the code i got

```
function searchDatabase(query) {
  // For each object in array
  for(var object of SampleArray) {

    // Get list values of object
    var lists = Object.values(object)

    // For each list of object
    for(var list of lists) {

      // For each item of list
     for(var item of list) {

     // Look for item matching query. Locally convert to lower case to
     // avoid case sensitivity issues
     if(item.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
      return object
     }
    }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: check this out https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/javascript-find-object-array-based-objects-property-rafael

Comment: It’s a good source, but I’m trying to create a music database based off of an array that I showed above. I will keep that example in mind though, thank you

Comment: NB: "Source" is not a *variable* but a *property* of an object.

Comment: I meant thanks for the link

Comment: Please add an example of a search and the expected result, as precise as possible. It is not clear whether you want to test the presence of a property or whether that property has a certain value.

Comment: I most certainly will

Comment: I don't see any change in your question that specifies unambiguously what the expected output should be. And an example array that only has one object in it is not very representative. Please give an example with at least 3 array elements, a *concrete* search you would like to do, and the *exact* output (in JS terms) you would expect from that search. It is important to know whether you expect an object, a property name, a boolean, a property value, all or some of those. Please clarify.

Comment: Please note, yesterday i joined stack overflow, so I’m still learning about the whole question thing

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something this to search for a key in array then try this:
You can return true or false if required. Thanks

```
function findObjectByKey(array, key) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i][key] != undefined) {
            console.log("Key Found");
        }
    }
}
```

findObjectByKey(objArray, 'source');

Comment: For the array.length part, can i use it with the array in my question?

Comment: It works, but it doesn’t show the source, it only shows the first array

Comment: It will be hard to tell, if you can host your data and code some where then it will help better to understand.